# How do I put multiple textarea lines and keep them counting individually?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var price = 0;
var tax = price * .12;
var total = price + tax + 3;
var spcount = 0;
var mpcount = 0;
var lpcount = 0;
var xpcount = 0;
var account = 0;
var apcount = 0;
var sp = spcount + " Small Pizza ";

function sPizza() {
  price += 5;
  spcount++;
  if(order.value == "") {
order.value += spcount + " Small Pizza ";
  }
  else if(order2.value == "" && order.value !== sp && spcount = 1) {
order2.value += spcount + " Small Pizza ";  
  }
  else if(order.value == sp) {
order.value += spcount + " Small Pizza ";
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="button" value="Small" onclick="sPizza()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" value="Medium" onclick="mPizza()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" value="Large" onclick="lPizza()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" value="Extra Large" onclick="xPizza()"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Extra Cheese" onclick="addCheese()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" value="Add Pop" onclick="addPop()">
</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">
  <label for="order">Order:</label><br>
  <textarea name="order" id="order"></textarea><br>
<textarea name="order2" id="order2" style="border-top-style: none;"></textarea><br>
<textarea name="order3" id="order3" style="border-top-style: none;"></textarea><br>
<textarea name="order4" id="order4" style="border-top-style: none;"></textarea><br>
<textarea name="order5" id="order5" style="border-top-style: none;"></textarea><br>
<textarea name="order6" id="order5" style="border-top-style: none; border-bottom-style: solid;"></textarea><br>
</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="formSubmit()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" value="Cancel Order" onclick="formCancel()">
</p>
```

So we have a school project where we make a pizza order form. We need to make a program that:

- Has 6 buttons for 4 different pizzas and 2 add-ons
- When you click a button, it adds to the total price and displays the order in a textarea

I already have this code and I've been working on it for hours with no success. I didn't want the form to overflow and only have 6 lines as its capacity for the 6 products, and the duplicates just get counted and printed as "# Product".

If you can also see in my HTML code I just tried making 6 different textareas with different border styles and covered up with a div to make it look like it's a single one, which is just a desperate measure.

Comment: My problem is that whenever I click on a product, it lets another on the second line, but when I click the first product again, it replaces the other. My code's just broken, I've tried a variety of ways already.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I didn't. Was about to rework my own edit when I saw it was rejected. I can't explain...

Comment: Ok I see, No worries..

Answer (score 0):

You've an Invalid left-hand side in assignment :

```
if(order2.value == "" && order.value !== sp && spcount = 1)
______________________________________________________^^^
```

Should be :

```
if(order2.value == "" && order.value !== sp && spcount == 1)
```

Hope this helps.